# OAuth Error#210 User Not Visible

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

```
$status = $_SESSION['fbglobalconn']->api('/'.$user.'/feed','post',$attachment);
```

Error 210 OAuth Exception User Not Visible

This line of code works for some profiles in posting but others it wont and stops the loop.  Any reasons for the error? Any particular work around so the loop wont just stop but still will continue?

Also is there a way for me to say find out who these supposed users who are not visible? Sorry one more question, how do I get a return http code if the api worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any reasons for the error?

The user does not allow posts on his wall to be made by you.

> Any particular work around so the loop wont just stop but still will continue?

*Catch* the exception. That’s what they’re for.

Comment: Used a try catch combined with facebook error reporting code, fixed the problem appreciate the tips.